# Save log queries across different application insights instances

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In Azure Application Insights Logs, I can save custom queries into the "query explorer", but they are saved per Application Insights instance. I want to use the same query in a different AI Logs.

Note I don't want to query data across AI instances, just save and reuse the queries themselves without duplicating them.

Comment: I'd love that as well - I've had to replicate queries across AI containers for all my environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft seems to now have implemented this functionality in Azure. When you save a query, you can select a "Query Pack" to save it to, and the query pack can be used by any log analytics instance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently the saved query can only be used by the current Application Insights instance. A user feedback is already raised [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/39243223-export-saved-queries).

You can consider using [workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview)(Note that workbook is not designed for this and has some limitations, but we can use it to save query and use the query in other Application insights instances).

Steps are as below:

1.Nav to azure portal -> one of your application insights -> click Workbooks -> create an empty template:

[image]

2.Click Add -> then click "add query":

[image]

3.In the new page, you can select one of your Application Insights from the `Resource dropdown` -> then write your query code -> then click the "Run Query" button to check the results-> click Save button to save the workbook:

[image]

4.Next time, if you want to re-use the query written in `step 3`, just open the saved workbook -> click the Edit button to enter into edit mode:

[image]

5.Then click the Edit button in edit mode:

[image]

6.In the new page, click the Change button to select another Application Insights. Then the query will be based the new selected Application insights:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, great description for the workaround.

Comment: @jhyot could you please accept it as answer if it's helpful? Thanks:).

Comment: I'll wait a few days if anything other pops up and then will do that.